# pagerjs newbie - using without node.js?

Tags: javascript, pagerjs

Newbie question.  I thought pagerjs was a client-side framework that works with knockout.  So why do I need node.js to install?  Is there any way to use without node?  Or am I mistaken about how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you do not need node.js to install pager.js (but you can use npm to install it if you like). Download the pager.js-file (https://raw.github.com/finnsson/pagerjs/master/pager.js) directly and include it just as any other js-file (both AMD and non-AMD is supported).